# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

Tags: javascript, animation, next.js, typeerror

I followed below tutorial on text reveal animation and tried to reflect that on Next.Js. But is gives me error message saying "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')"

Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0yjWtaajgw

[TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYZW.png)

```
'use client';

import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import styles from './title.module.css';

import anime from "animejs";

import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";


export default function Title() {

useEffect(() => {

    textWrapper = document.querySelector(`.${styles.title}`);
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
        /\S/g,
        "<span className={styles.letter}>$&</span>"
    );

    anime.timeline().add({
        targets: ".${styles.title} .${styles.letter}",
        translateY: [-200, 0],
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 1500,
    });
  

}, [])


    return (
        <section>
            <h1 className={styles.title}>Web Designer</h1>
        </section>
    )
}
```

I tried to add useReff and doesn't seems workings.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing regular quotes with backticks. You must use backticks when interpolating values.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the class name as below code

```
let textWrapper = document.querySelector("title");
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
    /\S/g,
    "<span className={styles.letter}>$&</span>"
);

<h1 className="title">Web Designer</h1>
```